# Emulate bluetooth/wifi connection on AVDs

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am looking for testing how my app sends files via wifi-direct and(or) bluetooth. Is there a way I could emulate a connection between a PC and the emulator and send files? Or is it possible to emulate this between 2 AVDs?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
The emulator does not support Bluetooth. Just can`t.

Comment: Ok Thanks dude. I'll do it with physical device.